# Insert PHP LDAP results into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, ldap

I'm trying to insert data that I'm grabbing from an LDAP query into a MySQL table

with the below code I've managed to insert the first result but can't quite workout how to get the others.

```
$displayname = isset($attr['displayname'][0]) ? $attr['displayname'][0] : "[no name set]";
$lastlogon = isset($attr['lastlogon'][0]) ? $attr['lastlogon'][0] : "[No logon date]";
$lastlogon_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $lastlogon/10000000-11644473600);

$sql = "INSERT INTO data (id, name, logon)
 VALUES ('', '$displayname', '$lastlogon_date')";

if ($conn->query($sql)) {
echo "Inserted logon date/time for $displayname ";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: You're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and need to show more details of these "other results".

Comment: it's only an internal script and can you suggest which other parts you may need? as it's a fairly large file

Comment: Do you have `other results` in this array `$attr` ?

Comment: Yep Newage

I took the script from the top on here: https://samjlevy.com/mydap-v4/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write every one of results in a loop. Example:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($attr); $i++) {
    $displayname = isset($attr['displayname'][$i]) ? $attr['displayname'][$i] : "[no name set]";
    $lastlogon = isset($attr['lastlogon'][$i]) ? $attr['lastlogon'][$i] : "[No logon date]";
    $lastlogon_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $lastlogon/10000000-11644473600);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO data (id, name, logon)
     VALUES ('', '$displayname', '$lastlogon_date')";

    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "Inserted logon date/time for $displayname ";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Or you can collect all values for one insert.

Comment: it seems to insert a load of [no logon date]'s with the first row but doesn't grab any others

Comment: I don't know about your array. It's example work with a loop. If you give your array I can get better example.